# Outputting values in different arrays that have the same key

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have n number of arrays as such:

```
$array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$array2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$array3 = array('w', 'x', 'y', 'z');
```

and I wanted to echo their values where the key is the same, i.e.

a1w ... b2x ... etc

I have a way to do this, but currently I have to manually input the length of the  new array, like this -

```
$i=0;
while($i<n) {
    $arraylist[] = array($array1[$i], $array2[$i], $array3[$i], ...$arrayn[$i])
    $i++;
}

$i=0;
foreach($arraylist as $s) {
    $b=0;
    foreach($s as $a) {
        echo $s[$b];
        $b++;
        }
    echo " ... ";
    $i++;
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having to manually set the length of n (the number of arrays). Also, is there way to make this an easier/more efficient process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
$array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$array2 = array(1, 2, 3);
$array3 = array('w', 'x','y', 'z');

function printByIndex(...$arrays) {
    $amount  = count($arrays);
    $biggest = count(max($arrays));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $biggest; ++$i) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < $amount; ++$j) {
            echo isset($arrays[$j][$i]) ? $arrays[$j][$i] : '';
        }
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}

printByIndex($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

**Output:**

```
a1w
b2x
c3y
dz
e
f
```

[Sandbox Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba29398253a1f786520bbfcbe2d59b1380befab7)

**Edit:** Quick explanation;

- Function takes in 1..n Arrays.
- Calculates how many arrays were passed and which array has the most keys.
- Loop from 0 to the size of the largest array
- Loop from 0 to the amount of arrays passed
- Print out their indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$array2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4 , 5);
$array3 = array('w', 'x', 'y', 'z');
$maxArray = max(sizeof($array1),sizeof($array2),sizeof($array3));
$i=0;
while($i<$maxArray)
{
    if(!empty($array1[$i])){ echo $array1[$i];}
    if(!empty($array2[$i])){ echo $array2[$i];}
    if(!empty($array3[$i])){ echo $array3[$i];}
echo "...";
$i++;
}
```

this is for any size of array to capture all key for displaying expected pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$array2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$array3 = array('w', 'x', 'y', 'z');
```

if all array have same size then we can use size of any array.

```
$i=0;
while($i<sizeof($array1))
{
echo $array1[$i].$array2[$i].$array3[$i];
echo "...";
$i++;
}

you can print your pattern using this way.
```

Comment: Got to be careful with this; If `$array1` isn't the biggest array, you won't capture all the keys.

Comment: i have mention there if all array have same size then we can use it.